# Using PrintDlg on Vista x64 does not work, works fine on 32 bit and XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, printing, vista64

We've got an app with some legacy printer "setup" code that we are still using `PrintDlg` for. We use a custom template to allow the user to select which printer to use for various types of printing tasks (such as reports or drawings) along with orientation and paper size/source.

It works on XP and 32-bit Vista, but on Vista x64 it gets a `CDERR_MEMLOCKFAILURE` via `CommDlgExtendedError()`. I've tried running it with just the bare-bones input in the `PRINTDLG` structure, but if the parameters include `PD_PRINTSETUP` or `PD_RETURNDEFAULT`, I get that error.

Since the printer selection / page setup has been split into `PageSetupDlg` and `PrintDlgEx`, there is no apparent easy transition without changing a fair amount of code and/or changing completely how we present printing and printer setup to the user.

Has anyone seen this problem on 64-bit Vista, and have you found any work-arounds?

**Notes:**
Application runs as Administrator due to other constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a related post on the Microsoft forums: [On Vista x64, DocumentProperties fails from UAC-elevated process](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2677398&SiteID=1)

I've verified with a sample program that PrintDlg running as non-admin works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post on the Quicken Community forum: [Solution to Printing Problems Vista 64 Quicken 2008](http://www.quickencommunity.com/webx/Forums/Quicken%20Personal%20Finance%20Software%20Forum%20for%20Windows/Printing%20in%20Quicken/531/26?5), and the related FAQ: [What if I'm unable to print, or receive "Error communicating with printer"?](https://quicken.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/quicken.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=5893) and the recommendation to use an emulation printer.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem as I was adding printing to my app. I was using the PrintDialog class and it works great if it is compiled as a 32-bit app, but doesn't even pop up when compiled in 64-bit mode. No error messages, no nothing. The call to ShowDialog just returns immediately. (Note that I am running 64-bit Vista.)

I tried using PrintDlg, but that has the same problem. I looked online and found a lot of people we're having similar problems though apparently not everybody who has 64-bit Vista sees this. Anyway, I finally decided to write my own version of PrintDialog (borrowing from code online), but this was a bit tricky (as some of the online code had bugs) and since I never did find a complete example online for this, I thought I would post my solution here.

Note, my version leaves a few things out of the dialog, like the "Print range", "Copies", and "Print to file". This should be easy to add but my app didn't need them. I also couldn't figure out what the "Type:" field was displaying so I left it out as well.

Here's what the dialog looks like:

[alt text http://www.geocities.com/deancooper2000/PrintDialog64.jpg](http://www.geocities.com/deancooper2000/PrintDialog64.jpg)

And here's my code (I've left the designer code out as it should be pretty easy to recreate):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Printing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Zemetrics.Diagnostics;

namespace Utils
{
/// <summary>
/// The PrintDialog64 class replaces the standard PrintDialog with one that works in Vista x64
/// </summary>
public partial class PrintDialog64 : Form
{
    #region Private members 
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint="DocumentPropertiesW")]
    private static extern int DocumentProperties(IntPtr hWnd,IntPtr hPrinter,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pDeviceName,IntPtr pDevMode,IntPtr devModeIn,int fMode);

    [DllImport("winspool.drv")] private static extern int    OpenPrinter(string pPrinterName,out IntPtr hPrinter,IntPtr pDefault);
    [DllImport("winspool.drv")] private static extern int    ClosePrinter(IntPtr phPrinter);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] private static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(IntPtr hMem);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] private static extern int    GlobalUnlock(IntPtr hMem);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] private static extern int    GlobalFree(IntPtr hMem);

    private const int DM_PROMPT     = 4;
    private const int DM_OUT_BUFFER = 2;
    private const int DM_IN_BUFFER  = 8;

    private List<PrinterItem> printers;
    private string            printerName;
    private string            originalName;
    private IntPtr            hDevMode = IntPtr.Zero;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the printer that prints the document       
    /// </summary>
    public PrinterSettings PrinterSettings { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating the PrintDocument used to obtain PrinterSettings.       
    /// </summary>
    public PrintDocument Document { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a replacement for the standard PrintDialog with one that works in Vista x64
    /// </summary>
    public PrintDialog64()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region PrinterItem class
    /// <summary>
    /// The PrinterItem class holds a reference to a PrintQueue and allows us to sort a list based on printer name
    /// </summary>
    private class PrinterItem : IComparable<PrinterItem>
    {
        #region Private members
        private PrinterItem() {}
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct a PrinterItem by supplying a reference to the printer's PrintQueue class
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// \param[in]  printer Reference to PrintQueue class for this printer
        public PrinterItem(PrintQueue printer)
        {
            Printer = printer;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reference to PrintQueue class for this printer
        /// </summary>
        public PrintQueue Printer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The string for this class is simply the FullName of the printer
        /// </summary>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Printer.FullName;
        }

        #region IComparable<PrinterItem> Members
        /// <summary>
        /// Implements IComparable interface to allow sorting of PrinterItem classes (based on printer name)
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// \param[in]  other The other PrinterItem class that we are to compare this one to
        public int CompareTo(PrinterItem other)
        {
            return other.Printer.FullName.CompareTo(this.Printer.FullName);
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    private List<PrinterItem> GetPrinters()
    {
        List<PrinterItem> printers = new List<PrinterItem>();

        EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes[] Queue_types = {EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local,EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections};

        try {
            using (LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer())
                foreach (PrintQueue printer in server.GetPrintQueues(Queue_types))
                    printers.Add(new PrinterItem(printer));                 
            } catch {}

        printers.Sort();
        return printers;                
    }

    private void PrintDialog64_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        originalName = Document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        printers     = GetPrinters();
        int index=0, i=0;

        foreach(PrinterItem printer in printers) {
            nameComboBox.Items.Add(printer.ToString());

            if (printer.ToString() == originalName) index = i;
            i++;
            }

        nameComboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
    }

    private void nameComboBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = nameComboBox.Text;

        foreach(Object field in nameComboBox.Items)
            if (((string) field).ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower())) nameComboBox.SelectedItem = field;

        if (nameComboBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            nameComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void nameComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintQueue printer = printers[nameComboBox.SelectedIndex].Printer;

        if (hDevMode!=IntPtr.Zero) GlobalFree(hDevMode);

        PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName = printer.FullName;
        hDevMode                    = PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode(Document.DefaultPageSettings);            

        statusValue .Text = printer.QueueStatus.ToString()=="None" ? "Ready" : printer.QueueStatus.ToString();
        whereValue  .Text = printer.Location=="" ? printer.QueuePort.Name : printer.Location;
        commentValue.Text = printer.Comment;
    }

    private void propertiesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr handle;
        OpenPrinter(printerName, out handle, IntPtr.Zero);

        IntPtr pDevMode = GlobalLock( hDevMode );
        DocumentProperties(this.Handle, handle, printerName, pDevMode, pDevMode, DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_PROMPT | DM_OUT_BUFFER);
        GlobalUnlock( hDevMode );

        PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode( hDevMode );
        PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.SetHdevmode( hDevMode );
        ClosePrinter(handle);
    }

    private void pageDefaultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PageSetupDialog setup = new PageSetupDialog(); 
        setup.PageSettings = Document.DefaultPageSettings;

        if (setup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            if (hDevMode!=IntPtr.Zero) GlobalFree(hDevMode);

            hDevMode = PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode( Document.DefaultPageSettings = setup.PageSettings );
            }
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hDevMode!=IntPtr.Zero) GlobalFree(hDevMode);
    }

    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hDevMode!=IntPtr.Zero) GlobalFree(hDevMode);

        PrinterSettings.PrinterName = originalName;
    }
}
}
```